# cv2.error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am new to python. I am trying open my webcam using the cv2 model.
But I have errors like this I can't understand.

This is my python code: -

```
import cv2

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = video.read()
    cv2.imshow("WindowFrame", frame)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k == ord('q'):
        break
    video.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is my error:

[image]

Comment: You should use a debugger, and inspect `frame` after the call to `video.read()`. My bet is that you fail to get a valid frame from the VideoCapture / camera.

Comment: Line "video.release()" must be outside of while loop. You are destroying camera object you are trying to get image data.

Comment: please take the [tour] and review [ask]. you should have searched for this issue. there are answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time when you read !_src.empty() in your stacktrace it means that your frame, that should be a numpy tensor with numbers within it, is empty.

I suggest you to edit your code in the following way:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    if video.isOpened():
        ret, frame = video.read()
        if ret:
            cv2.imshow("WindowFrame", frame)
   
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

So first you create the `VideoCapture()` object specifying the index of the camera

> VideoCapture (int index) --> Open a camera for video capturing

Then, inside the `while True` you check if the camera object has already been initialized with `isOpened()`

> isOpened () const --> Returns true if video capturing has been initialized already.

and if this is true then you can start reading frames from the camera. You do this with `video.read()` which returns a frame (in particular it reads the next frame) and a boolean value (we called it `ret`) that tells you if the frame is available or not. Thus, if `ret == True`, we show the frame with `cv2.imshow("WindowFrame", frame)`.

Furthermore, inside your code there's an error. Since `release()` method closes the camera, you can not put it inside the `while True` loop

> virtual void  release () --> Closes video file or capturing device

Also `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` must stay outside the loop because otherwise you keep opening and closing the window which shows you the frame.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html